# Why am I receiving the error The Requested Resource can only be accessed via SSL, while using the Sitecore.Services.Client

Tags: ssc

So, I am trying to access my Sitecore Media library via Sitecore.Services.Client with the following code:
I have read the Developers Guide for the Sitecore Services Client, under the Security section. I would like to know if I am missing anything? I am receiving the error "The Requested Resource can only be accessed via SSL"

```
 public static void PostMedia2()
        {
            try
            {
                var authUrl = "https://intranet-dev.university.edu/sitecore/api/ssc/auth/login";
                var authData = new Authentication
                {
                    Domain = "sitecore",
                    Username = "admin",
                    Password = "b" 
                };

                var authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(authUrl);

                authRequest.Method = "POST";
                authRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

                var requestAuthBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(authData);

                var authDatas = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(requestAuthBody);

                using (var dataStream = authRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    dataStream.Write(authDatas, 0, authDatas.Length);
                }
                CookieContainer cookies = new CookieContainer();

                authRequest.CookieContainer = cookies;

                var authResponse = authRequest.GetResponse();

                Console.WriteLine($"Login Status:\n\r{((HttpWebResponse)authResponse).StatusDescription}");

                authResponse.Close();

                var emailObj = new ItemRequest
                {
                    ItemName = "Class Lists Phase Resuls",
                    TemplateID = "{0603F166-35B8-469F-8123-E8D87BEDC171}",
                    Title = "Cless List Test June",
                    Text = "Class List Test June 2020"
                };
                var url = "https://intranet-dev.university.edu/sitecore/api/ssc/item/sitecore%2Fmedia%20library%PtrTest4";

                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.CookieContainer = cookies;

                var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(emailObj);

                var data = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(requestBody);

                using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    dataStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }

              //  var response = request.GetResponse();

                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Item Status:\n\r{((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription}");
                }


            }

            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error occurred. Message: {ex.Message}.\r\n StackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}.\r\n InnerException: {ex.InnerException}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

The error is happening on the  var authResponse = authRequest.GetResponse();

I have changed the setting in my Sitecore.Services.Config

```
 <setting name="Sitecore.Services.SecurityPolicy" value="Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure.Web.Http.Security.ServicesOnPolicy, Sitecore.Services.Infrastructure" />
```

Are there other setting to configure?
Is there something that I need to do on the Server side?

I ran this Test to verify SSL

```
 public static void testSSL()
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://intranet-dev.chicagobooth.edu");
            //request.Method = "HEAD";
            //request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

            // Ignore Certificate validation failures (aka untrusted certificate + certificate chains)
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = ((sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true);

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

Comment: Can you try to add the following line of code `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;` between the `try` and the `var authUrl`

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately that did not work. I want to thank you for all of your help with this. it is so difficult to find any documentation on how to fix this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I once experienced a similar issue. The reason behind it was rule set on the Firewall. Due to this, any requests which were trying to hit our intranet website was returning an error.

The workaround for me was to remove the rule from the Firewall and the final solution was implemented by the System Admin.

Comment: Thank you, I will check with our Infrastructure guys and see what they need to do